# Jmeter -- How to Remove First Few Responses for Test

Tags: jmeter

Does anyone know how to remove the first few items when running a Jmeter response time test? I'm testing how fast a SOAP API responds.

When I test the response for say 20,000 hits, the first few responses invariably take WAY longer than the rest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [`jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_general) to specify reporting start date and time
2. JMeter .jtl result files are normal CSV files where `elapsed` column contains Response Time (in milliseconds) and `timeStamp` column is request start time (in form of [Unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/))

   So you can just manually remove first few rows using your favourite text editor and [regenerate reporting dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from the new file.
3. Another option which provides more flexibility is [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) where you can exclude results either by regular expression pattern or specify start and end offsets or both. You can install Filter Results Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image: JMeter Filter Results Tool Plugins Manager]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response! 
I tried #2 and it worked.
Here is what I did specifically:
I used a "View Results in Table" listener. In that listener there is a box that says "Write results to file".
I ran the test.
I opened the file in Notepad++ and removed the first line with the large time to connect.
Then, I used the "Response Time Graph"  and opened up the file using the "Read from file" box.
The really long first time to connect was not there anymore!